# Symmetrization by ghost-sample probabilistic argument in Vapnik-Chervonenkis inequality proof

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I am trying to resolve some compilation queries that arose in parsing the proof of the Vapnik-Chervonenkis inequality, and would appreciate some assistance on clarifying a particular step. The proof comes from a set of lecture notes by [Robert Nowak (2009)](https://nowak.ece.wisc.edu/SLT09/lecture19.pdf#page=2) closely following a similar strategy to the one outlined by [Devroye, Gyorfi and Lugosi (1996)](https://www.szit.bme.hu/%7Egyorfi/pbook.pdf#page=193) in their proof of the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem.

I am having trouble with the following line of the proof, extract provided further below:

$$\begin{multline}\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1} \left\{\left \vert \hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) \right \vert > \epsilon \right\} \mathbb{1} \left\{\left \vert \hat{R}'_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) \right \vert > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right\}  \right] 
\\= \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1} \left\{\left \vert \hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) \right \vert > \epsilon \right\} \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1} \left\{\left \vert \hat{R}'_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) \right \vert > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right\} \, \middle | \, D_n \right]  \right] 
\end{multline}$$

1. *Why is there a need to condition on the training sample $D_n = \{(X_i, Y_i) \}^n_{i=1}$ in the inner expectation, if it is the case that both the training sample $D_n$ and ghost sample $D_n' = \{(X_i', Y_i') \}^n_{i=1}$ are independently drawn from the same joint distribution, $D_n, D_n' \overset{i.i.d.}\sim P(X, Y)$?*

2. *If there is no redundancy in conditioning on the training sample $D_n$ due to independence, then what are the underlying distributions in all expectations?*

Here is an extract of the proof:

> [image]

---

My guess would be that the equality holds due to iterated expectations. But I'm not sure why this would be necessary due to independence of $D_n$ and $D_n'$. I will edit to include my scribblings in due course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equality can be made clearer by explicitly denoting the random variables with which each expectation is taken over. First, note that the outer expectation is with respect to both $D_n$ and $D_n'$. So, for the sake of clarity, I'll write
$$\mathbb{E}_{D_n, D_n'}\left[I\left\{|\hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) > \epsilon| \right\}I\left\{|\hat{R}_n'(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) < \epsilon/2| \right\}\right].$$

We can then leverage 1. the independence of $D_n$ and $D_n'$, and 2. The fact that only $\hat{R}_n'(\tilde{f})$ depends on $D_n'$, to get:

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_{D_n, D_n'}&\left[I\left\{|\hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) > \epsilon| \right\}I\left\{|\hat{R}_n'(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) < \epsilon/2| \right\}\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{D_n} \mathbb{E}_{D_n'}\left[I\left\{|\hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) > \epsilon| \right\}I\left\{|\hat{R}_n'(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) < \epsilon/2| \right\}\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{D_n}\left[I\left\{|\hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) > \epsilon| \right\}\mathbb{E}_{D_n'}\left[I\left\{|\hat{R}_n'(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) < \epsilon/2| \right\}\right]\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{D_n}\left[I\left\{|\hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) > \epsilon| \right\}\mathbb{E}_{D_n'}\left[I\left\{|\hat{R}_n'(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) < \epsilon/2| \right\}\bigg\vert D_n \right]\right],\\
\end{align*}
$$
where the last step was due to the fact that $p(D_n' | D_n) = p(D_n')$.